# Automatically run django unittests

Tags: django

I want to create a script to automatically run the tests in django.  So I want to perform the equivalent of python manage.py test myapp within python and store wether the test failed or not as a variable.

So if the test works:

```
variable = True
```

if the test doesn't work:

```
variable = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with your own test runner using [suite_result](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.simple.DjangoTestSuiteRunner.suite_result).  Related code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/simple.py#L343-344)